How can I configure idp endpoints like idp login url, logout url, fingerprint in pac4j saml when idp metadata file / url not available
I have IDP Single sign on url, single logout url, x509 fingerprint. While creating saml2client in pac4j vertx lib, how can I configure it manually to create config and saml2client object and use it further as I saw only url based idp metadata and file based idp metadata being used.

I guess you are referring to this setup available in the demo: https://github.com/pac4j/vertx-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/pac4j/vertx/config/Pac4jConfigurationFactory.java#L111

No, in the library idp metadata can be set retrieved from url, file. But, I am looking for configuring this manually and using it

The parsing of the IdP metadata is ensured by the SAML2IdentityProviderMetadataResolver built in the internalInit method of the SAML2Configuration. This is where you should do some customisation.
